# getCurrentPlace onResult Does Not Return Results

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have been trying to test the getCurrentPlace() method for the Google Places API. When I first tested it a few times, it was working no problem, but now all of a sudden it has stopped working. I've uninstalled the app, deleted the code and re-pasted from the documentation, closed Android Studio. I have no idea what is going wrong and the logs aren't erring, they just do not log what used to log.

```
View.OnClickListener getNearbyPlaces = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        places = new FindNearbyPlaces();
        placesArray = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            placesArray = places.findNearbyPlaces(mCurrentLocation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (PlacesAttributes place : placesArray) {
            Log.i("Name: ", place.getName());
            Log.i("Lat: ", String.valueOf(place.getLat()));
            Log.i("Lng: ", String.valueOf(place.getLng()));
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i("help", "");
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i("Place", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });


    }
};
```

That is the code chunk that I have. The first three log statements in the beginning run their course, but the log statements in onResult do not, not even the Log.i("help", ""). I had the beginning log statements where they are when it did work, so they shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you've provided returns early if the app doesn't have the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. Maybe that's what's happening. Check that the permission is granted (Settings->Apps->AppName->Permissions).

Comment: I did check that just to make sure. But what you cannot see, which my apologies, the above statements before getCurrentPlace() enact another function of mine which does a PlaceSearch via URL, so that takes in my location and returns nearby places via Logs.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around (enabling Places Android API, adding more keys, deleting keys, renaming keys, renaming "API_KEY" in the "name" field under meta-data), it appears the app is finally giving me results all of a sudden. I honestly do not know which action I took that solved it, but for now it appears it is working.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times what folks miss is that the Error is most likely linked to the fact the device's location services are turned off. The Error is too generic to let you the developer know what's going on, and often time results in developers loosing hours if not days trying to figure out whats going on.

Check Location Services under the device's settings

Answer (score 0):

You should check your connection.

```
 GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```